# DevExpress controls in Sitecore not posting back

Tags: devexpress, sitecore

I'm having some issues getting DevExpress controls working in Sitecore (7.5). I've verified that it is an issue with using the controls in Sitecore by using the same code in an aspx page outside the Sitecore solution (but in the same IIS site).

The issue is that on postback of a DevExpress Combobox control, I am not getting any selected values. I've tried the following;

Added to web.config:

```
<rendering>
    <typesThatShouldNotBeExpanded>
        <type>DevExpress.Web</type>
    </typesThatShouldNotBeExpanded>
</rendering>
```

Also tried adding DXR.axd to the Sitecore "IgnoreUrlPrefixes" setting in the web.config.
I have also tried setting EnableCallbackMode="false" on the DevEx control.

This is my test code I used, which worked in a normal aspx page, but not part of a Sublayout.

ASPX:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sc" Namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" %>

<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="ASPxPopupControl1" runat="server" ShowOnPageLoad="true">
    <ContentCollection>
        <dx:PopupControlContentControl>
            <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout1" runat="server">
                <Items>
                    <dx:LayoutGroup Caption="Testing">
                        <Items>
                            <dx:LayoutItem>
                                <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                    <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                        <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" Text="ASPxLabel" AssociatedControlID="ComboBox"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBoxLoja" runat="server" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/DevEx/{0}/styles.css"
                                            CssPostfix="DevEx" ValueField="codigo" SpriteCssFilePath="~/App_Themes/DevEx/{0}/sprite.css"
                                            ValueType="System.Guid" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Spacing="0" EnableCallbackMode="false">
                                            <LoadingPanelImage Url="~/App_Themes/DevEx/Editors/Loading.gif">
                                            </LoadingPanelImage>
                                            <Columns>
                                                <dx:ListBoxColumn Caption="Loja" FieldName="nome" />
                                            </Columns>
                                            <LoadingPanelStyle ImageSpacing="5px">
                                            </LoadingPanelStyle>
                                        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                    </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                            </dx:LayoutItem>
                        </Items>
                    </dx:LayoutGroup>
                    <dx:LayoutItem>
                        <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                            <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                <dx:ASPxButton runat="server" Text="ASPxButton" OnClick="Button_Click"></dx:ASPxButton>
                            </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                        </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                    </dx:LayoutItem>
                </Items>
            </dx:ASPxFormLayout>
            <asp:Literal Text="" runat="server" ID="Output" />
        </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
    </ContentCollection>
</dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

CS:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ASPxComboBoxLoja.DataSource = CreateRightListDataSource();
            ASPxComboBoxLoja.DataBind();
        }

        private IEnumerable CreateRightListDataSource()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                yield return new { codigo = Guid.NewGuid(), nome = "nome " + i };
            }

        }

        protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string retVal = ASPxComboBoxLoja.Value.ToString();
            Output.Text = retVal;
        }
```

An error occurs on the button click where it is trying to retrieve the Value. It is null (as is the selected item). Error on screen / in Sitecore logs:

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any experience getting DevExpress controls working in Sitecore? I'm sure I am doing something daft.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Sitecore logs? When you click the button, are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Hi @JayS, nothing in the logs apart from what I see on the screen (Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object error). I'll update the question above to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: Do the devexpress controls emit JavaScript and call http modules? If so Have you checked your console/ fiddler to see any underlying requests going on on the page?

Comment: Hi @goldengrahams, no errors when running fiddler. On my page outside of Sitecore I get the form data, i.e. "ASPxPopupControl1$ASPxFormLayout1$ASPxComboBoxLoja$DDD$L = e330d2cc-92ce-4af0-b8bd-38e1ab5c2488"

When doing the same via a Sitecore page, I still get the data on postback:

"dbcontent_0$ASPxPopupControl1$ASPxFormLayout1$ASPxComboBoxLoja$DDD$L = dd78709d-1777-47fe-9225-8b3327e117af"

However at this point I do get the obj. ref. error.

Comment: FYI it does look like there is a problem with Sitecore and using some .net controls. If you have access to SDN, the article may be found here: https://sdn.sitecore.net/scrapbook/listview%20and%20datapager%20under%20sitecore%20context.aspx. I've tried fiddling with the <typesThatShouldNotBeExpanded> setting in the web.config, but no luck as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I managed to resolve the issue by changing the AutomaticDataBind setting in the config. i.e. SC include file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="AutomaticDataBind">
        <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Changing `<typesThatShouldNotBeExpanded>` seemed to be the right thing to do; however it seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but this feels like a .NET event cycle issue with postbacks.You are rebinding the datasource on every page load, even postbacks. This will often mess with view state. Have you tried wrapping your databinding with an `if(!IsPostBack)`?

**EDIT:** I also just noted that you are generating a new GUID each time you render the page. I'm not sure what Codigo is, but your first load will have a different GUID than on postback.

Comment: Hi @jay unfortunately, with devexpress controls you have to bind the data to the control on each round trip to the server. I ran into this issue before (ref: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18649). Also I was generating a new GUID each just to create some test data. Thanks.